# 500 Server Error HTML returned from MVC AJAX call when plain text specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to return plain text from my MVC AJAX methods that indicates an error code.  This is working fine on my dev machine, but when deployed to a server (Win2008 R2) I am always getting the HTML of the 500.htm page back in the error.responseText from my AJAX call instead of the text I specified.  Any ideas why I would not get back the plain text I intended?

Here is my error handling logic in my controller.

```
    protected override void OnException(
        ExceptionContext filterContext
        )
    {
        try
        {
            Error error = ControllerCommon.ProcessException(filterContext);

            // return error
            filterContext.Result = HandleError(error.Type);
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Instance.LogImportantInformation(ex.Message, 0, Constants.EventSourcePortal);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods and Members

    private ActionResult HandleError()
    {
        return HandleError(Error.ErrorType.Unknown);
    }

    private ActionResult HandleError(
        Error.ErrorType errorType
        )
    {
        // set return status code
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        Logger.Instance.LogImportantInformation(((int)errorType).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 0, Constants.EventSourcePortal);

        // return error type
        return Content(((int)errorType).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "text/plain");
    }
```

Here is the header that I get back from the Server.

Response Headers
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    text/html
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Mon, 20 Jun 2011 16:00:42 GMT
Content-Length  1208
Request Headers
Host    pqompo2test01.dns.microsoft.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Accept  text/html, */*
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer https://pqompo2test01.dns.microsoft.com/Incident/List
Content-Length  330
Cookie  MC1=GUID=111c287d88c64447a63719bb2c858981&HASH=7d28&LV=20114&V=3; A=I&I=AxUFAAAAAACJCAAAMuSpPH1Citx6nZO0iHfvdA!!&CS=116|9n002j21b03; WT_FPC=id=131.107.0.73-1717525904.30146426:lv=1308581948698:ss=1308581948698; MUID=7F438FBFEEE948D88DA06B04F6923159; MSID=Microsoft.CreationDate=04/20/2011 16:45:49&Microsoft.LastVisitDate=06/20/2011 15:59:10&Microsoft.VisitStartDate=06/20/2011 15:59:10&Microsoft.CookieId=4c7552d0-5e75-4e5e-98b9-4ca52421a738&Microsoft.TokenId=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff&Microsoft.NumberOfVisits=27&Microsoft.CookieFirstVisit=1&Microsoft.IdentityToken=AA==&Microsoft.MicrosoftId=0668-8044-9161-9043; ANON=A=FA4FB528F204DDFA69239A4FFFFFFFFF&E=b4d&W=4; NAP=V=1.1&E=af3&C=hJtCCJq27admlaiwmdzvTmnAwIEVXv1jFR2I2bJ-gncMGQOJce96RQ&W=4; mcI=Wed, 27 Apr 2011 16:48:43 GMT; omniID=fd752842_58d3_4833_9a0f_d0e1e3bbfef3; WT_NVR_RU=0=msdn:1=:2=; ASP.NET_SessionId=dbcqi222tehjorefcopchuzu; MS0=7fc23d65df4241c89554b502149ccc13; MICROSOFTSESSIONCOOKIE=Microsoft.CookieId=94c8a34f-9184-4e10-84c5-2b9c43c7a962&Microsoft.CreationDate=06/20/2011 15:59:10&Microsoft.LastVisitDate=06/20/2011 15:59:10&Microsoft.NumberOfVisits=1&SessionCookie.Id=04DF98242DBD0730C9388487546F2F37; RPSMCA=FAAaARSsz90pZKmFSg5n0wbtR5MnQAldBwNmAAAEgAAACDNAEUimN1wb2AD%2Bp1PnEJUdd7n5VumQIQerCQYdD5IEd6ZCDEshkiTkvVl5a9eA6%2B9a0Os/1FpoqtvsGYMdWUUc98PUl5ZTo%2BFXAqxiZ9BL5D69OLCPsZEXitrZMulmKXFGQiAD5FqJY8JOOSJ1xptRwdkdrxGF8PuNit/Si87Ft7g4sF9vE878lMSx6TSmQq3nrurnBbdbUvDvwTKLoY0gAikOxJ7GmZoLw4kbzaLR/6/a/XSJFv%2BZ6uHsIwkMn6mndoZKfg3LLjDlCpozrHBlnKtgkn7yZXtd8Or420IXuPMUAF3gfp8VAkhKlVceTXpBv2h4gs6g; RPSMCSA=FAAaARSsz90pZKmFSg5n0wbtR5MnQAldBwNmAAAEgAAACEdSXDQ0SIKI2AC/tM6y7CeHdaKVAab/n/4TLKkF5/01jGkXR0vA07MTvS5vhwgjCPMs4zke%2B0jnB1DqOV2vI4VqQ/%2BOIYh52QkaLREoD5L718AjEJOQdDVRRZiIB51CiYtS0P/kgIkEtfDa5yuTr3w6V2IKhy2%2B6wVrP/UqxsJR%2BZ1QmGxtjv7eQVGdIndrkPx5e9wFqj1qEcf9FNfH0/uajuaTFaNmi/3dQfWuEKxGpoHWNxgoMf8PHLVi2hqltqK47OloCGqQGLPQPx0PSg1K73FTZHhl3%2BuxyNqyWJumKsAUAGuMUzFhTPsQ7JdOSfY2SYyHeaZP; RPSShare=1; MSPAuth=1NNm8kdmWAFrAuL2d8qOShxJKehL!CxEkCQvsgPdNGDqo0XFGsreQZ9GMVjiT1*bHPlGcNVsyfbVO7h!eY32bCNY7Farp2grIyEgAFv7YgJqWZN2Q87*LBZnZ0ASWmhPqe; MSPProf=1ZN*xhGN9GRXSO*HEmrISYo6cowSUbmxtIsYfqtHv!!VzEybb1I33*BdWWJrz54tkO5BzS3eTprAXL1LO9ELLBziO8Sm8WTzkSbV*E6ECcX9N92*AFiJztc4rlwCLQnMBhxlV0qzvlRN4dS1SajyzABZDNBTG*tdyqfnuP6jkSevAhuXYvnEuKZQKAF5fvgr4!oiBQ2KhnuH0$; **RequestVerificationToken_Lw**=TOS6XUQ+17bDOxh2T75NhhFy2KIJP5BP9MetB7cAa4i68ZEHIEpgE7xwQhzid/YiZCm4GsbW2zsJjlIxkB1hrhVGoU++E1I5BP9X2PyKn0O8tic84cWNz8QRjLDcaAcF4iYEQQ==; prmrsdninc=1

When I run locally on my Win7 machine I simply get the text back that I am expecting.

Comment: Try using firebug to see what message is coming back with the 500 error page it may clue you in to some syntax error or something. Check out the headers and the response tab and repost what you see.

Comment: I added the header that I am getting back from the server.  I don't see any errors, but it is returning text/html instead of text/plain as I had set.  It does work just fine on my Win7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem trying to return 500 pages containing only text for processing by telerik controls. Of course it worked tickity-boo on my development machine and failed when published up to the proper IIS servers.

This fixed it for me:

http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-04-13/asp_net-prevent-iis_75_overriding-custom-error-page-iis-default-error-page

Summary: Type putting a

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

line in your action